# Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: navigate is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im Learning ReactJS with NextJS making a project, register with firebase, Gogle, User and Email, all is OK, but when i try to make some Route, when I log in with google it works but it doesn't redirect to /dashboard and essentially that's what I need dont work, need help, this is my code:

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './login';
import Register from "./Register";
import Reset from "./Reset";
import Dashboard from "./dashboard";
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route exact path="/reset" element={<Reset />} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Nav from './components/Nav'
import login from './components/login'
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import App from './components/App.js';
import Modal from './components/modal';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
      <Head>   
       <title>Professional Resourses</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />           
      </Head>       
      <main>
        <Nav />    
        
        <Modal />
             
       </main>      
      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Nav component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { auth, logInWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordReset, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithGoogle } from "./firebase";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";



function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    
  }

 function Modal() {
 

    const handleOKClick = () => {
        setModalOn(false)
    }
    const handleCancelClick = () => {
        setModalOn(false)
    }
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const Modal = props => {
        if (!props.show){
          return null
        }
    }
        useEffect(() => {
      if (loading) {
        // maybe trigger a loading screen
        return;
      }
       if (user) navigate("/dashboard");
    }, [user, loading]);
         return (
            <div>
              CONTENT HERE IS A FORM
            </div>
          );
        }
      
  export default Modal
```

Comment: Your new component code looks very weird. The `Login` does nothing (or at least it seems so) .. It just defines some things that are do not seem to be used. Also, you are returning a `<div>` in the `Modal` that is never closed. The problem for your error is that you call `navigate` method defined in `Login` component in `Modal` component where it is not defined.

Comment: edited mi div tnks, u have reason

Comment: `navigate` is not defined in `Modal`

Comment: Yes, now i have this error.`Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`

Comment: Next.js has its own [built-in router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), you shouldn't use `react-router-dom`. See https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-react-router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation through next.js is done automatically
no need to react router
just import useRouter from next

see more about it
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Home = () => {
 const {push} = useRouter()
  return (
   <button onClick={() => push('dashboard')}>Click-me</button>
  )
}
```